# Python 3d Rendering not Working

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I'm making a 3d game engine with python using pyglet. If my vertex has 1 as the Z axis then everything renders okay, but anything else and it disappears.

My Obj loading code:

```
class Mesh:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.vbo = GLuint()
        self.size = 0
        self.name = name
        self.verts = []
        self.norms = []
        self.indis = []
        self.type = GL_TRIANGLES
    def Process(self,data):
        words = []
        for item in data: #For every line contained in data
            words = Get_Words(item, " ")
            if words[0] == "#": #Skip comments
                continue
            elif words[0] == "v": #Process Vertex Data
                self.verts.append(float(words[1])) #Vertex X
                self.verts.append(float(words[2])) #Vertex Y
                self.verts.append(float(words[3])) #Vertex Z
            elif words[0] == "vn": #Process Normal Data
                self.norms.append(float(words[1])) #Normal X
                self.norms.append(float(words[2])) #Normal Y
                self.norms.append(float(words[3])) #Normal Z
            elif words[0] == "f": #Process Face Data
                faces = []
                if len(words) == 5: #If mesh has quads instead of triangles
                    self.type = GL_QUADS #Set mesh type to quads
                for x in range(1,len(words)):
                    faces = Get_Words(words[x], "//") #Obj Face data example: 5//2
                    self.indis.append(GLuint(int(faces[0]))) #We only want the 5, 2 is the face number
    def Send(self):
        data = (GLfloat*len(self.verts))(*self.verts)

        self.size = sizeof(data)

        glGenBuffers(1, pointer(self.vbo))

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.size, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, self.size, data)
        del self.verts
        return data
    def Draw(self, *args):
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
        if len(args) == 0:
            glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, self.size)
        else:
            glDrawArrays(args[0], 0, self.size)
```

Right now I'm only rendering vertex data
Here is my main code:

```
window = New()
winset = Window()

winset.title = "Test"
winset.resizable = True
winset.icon = "icon.png"
winset.clear_color = vec4(0.2,0.2,0.2,1)

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

data = (GLfloat*6)(*[100,100, 200,200, 100,200])

vbo = GLuint()

glGenBuffers(1, pointer(vbo))

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(data), data)

d = []
d.append("v 300 300 1") #1 1 1
d.append("v 200 300 1") #-1 1 1
d.append("v 300 200 1") #1 -1 1
d.append("v 200 300 1")
d.append("v 300 200 1")
d.append("v 200 200 1")
d.append("v 200 300 -2")
d.append("v 300 200 -2")
d.append("v 200 200 -2")

cube = Mesh("Cube")

cube.Process(d)

cube.Send()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    #glColor3f(1,1,1)

    #glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)

    #glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
    #glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(data))

    glColor3f(1,1,0)

    cube.Draw(GL_TRIANGLES) #GL_TRIANGLES | GL_LINES

winset.Run(window)
```

window is the running window and winset is just settings that change the window

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I did wrong. I forgot to use glFrustum